# What could be the issue in the code getting AttributeError: module 'scrapy.utils.response' has no attribute 'css'?

Tags: python, css, scrapy

I have any issue, I am using scrapy frame work, where I am trying to match the content of an element with a CSS selector (normally this can’t be done alone with just CSS selector, so I am taking help of scrapy). But using respective API getting following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'scrapy.utils.response' has no attribute 'css'
```

Sample code:

```
from scrapy import utils
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http.response import Response

xPathToFieldBasedOnLabel = response.css('div.Button div:contains(' + keyword + ')').get()
```

Not sure what would be the wrong, bellow is the documentation to the api above.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Comment: You probably have `from scrapy.utils import response` somewhere. A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could get you more feedback, or even help you figure out the issue for yourself.

Comment: please describe how you created ```response```? what is ```keyword``` variable?

Comment: @Roman, Thanks for the message.
scrapy has two objects(  Request and Response ) used for crawling web sites, And keyword is internal variable passing in the query. But here the problem is though the API(response.css()) is from scrapy, its not recognising it.